# How can I monitor multiple iBeacons and change a UILabel based on each beacon?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, beacon

I'm having an issue with monitoring multiple beacons simultaneously. My code works fine with just one, but I can't seem to figure out how to monitor more than one beacon AND update the a UILabel.

The beacons are all being monitored and recognized when I turn them on, but my phone fails to show the correct labels in the view. It constantly shows "UNKOWN" in the distanceReading.text unless it's the last beacon in the function (Estimote).

I'm also having some other issues of updating a name for which beacon it is. I'm not sure how to call on the beacon identifier, which would be the ideal way (something like beacon.identifier). I've tried creating another variable and updating the name through each beacon scan, but it just scans the last one and doesn't change. I was hoping it would scan it WHEN it was detected, thus allowing me to change the variable as a new beacon is detected.

I've tried putting all the beacons in one startScanning() function, giving each unique UUID it's on variable and using locationManager.startMonitoring() and locationManager.startRangingBeacon() for each separate beacon. Then I tried creating a startScanning() function using parameters for each UUID, major, minor, and identifier, then calling the function for each beacon.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var distanceReading: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var beaconDict: [String: String]?
    var labelName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        alertShown = false

        view.backgroundColor = .gray  // default is in "unknown mode"

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedAlways {
            // Can we monitor beacons or not?
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                //  Can we detect the distance of a beacon?
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    startScanning(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "5A4BCFCE-174E-4BAC-A814-092E77F6B7E5")!, major: 123, minor: 456, identifier: "Apple Beacon", name: "Apple")
                    startScanning(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")!, major: 123, minor: 456, identifier: "Radius Beacon", name: "Radius")
                    startScanning(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "5AFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF")!, major: 123, minor: 456, identifier: "Red Bear Beacon", name: "Red Bear")
                    startScanning(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, major: 123, minor: 456, identifier: "Estimote", name: "Estimote")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func startScanning(uuid: UUID, major: UInt16, minor: UInt16, identifier: String, name: String) {
        let uuidApple = uuid
        let beaconRegion1 = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuidApple, major: major, minor: minor, identifier: identifier)
        locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion1)
        locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion1)
        labelName = name
    }

    func update(distance: CLProximity) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            switch distance {
            case .far:
                self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
                self.distanceReading.text = "FAR"
            case .near:
                self.view.backgroundColor = .orange
                self.distanceReading.text = "NEAR"
            case .immediate:
                self.view.backgroundColor = .red
                self.distanceReading.text = "RIGHT HERE"
            default:
                self.view.backgroundColor = .gray
                self.distanceReading.text = "UNKNOWN"
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        if let beacon = beacons.first {
            nameLabel.text = labelName
            update(distance: beacon.proximity)
        } else {
            update(distance: .unknown)
        }
    }
```

I expect that every time a new beacon is detected, my label changes accordingly. This works as intended for the beacon called LAST, but not the first three. The color changes, but the label refuses to change. I'd also like to figure out a way to call the identifier of the beacon that I set in CLBeaconRegion.

Answer (score 2):

Try looping through all the ranged beacons as in `for beacon in beacons` instead of just  working with the first one in the array as in `beacons.first`.

Comment: So I though about this, but I don't know how I'd test it. Right now I'm using a beacon app to test this, so I can only activate one beacon at a time (only one extra device). However, I still don't know if it would fix the issue because when I print(beacon) after checking of beacon == beacon.first, it will always print the correct beacon information. It just fails to update the distanceReading.text correctly (unless it's the last beacon) in my switch statement. If it's any of the first three beacons it just shows "UNKNOWN"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with the beacon name is that `labelName` is a single string and you set its value in `startScanning`. Each time you call, `startScanning` you overwrite the previous value of `labelName`. Since the final time you call `startScanning` you supply the name *Estimote* that is the value that you will always see in `nameLabel`.

You have a `beaconDict` property which shows you may have been thinking about this, but didn't proceed.

What I would do is create a `Beacon` struct to hold all of the properties of a beacon, including its `name`, create instances of this struct to pass to `startScanning` and store these instances in a `[String:Beacon]` dictionary. Use the string of the UUID as the key. Then, we you get a call back you can use the beacon identifier to find the corresponding `Beacon` from the dictionary and get its `name`.

As to why the distance is always unknown, David is right; you will be receiving 4 beacons in the `didRangeBeacons` callback. Since you only have one physical beacon all of the beacons other than the one you currently have active will be unknown, but you only look at the first.

You will probably find it easier to use a tableview with one row per beacon than a single label.

Comment: I did come to the same conclusion as you for the nameLabel issue. And you're correct, I tried a dictionary and failed. I haven't tried a custom struct yet, I should have thought of that! Then it might make my dictionary easier and fix the identifier issue. I do think there's more to the issue of the list of beacons though. I only have one beacon active at a time, so it only the "first" beacon is always the only beacon. And the distance actually does work, or at least the color portion. It's just the label that doesn't update from unknown, although, maybe the above solution will still fix it!

Comment: when you receive an update for an inactive beacon you change the text but not the colour, which is why you always see "unknown". The beacon distance for the active beacon was shown, but quickly overwritten by an inactive beacon. Add a print statement when you set the distance text and you will see what is happening. Again, a tableview will make this simpler

Comment: Okay I think I see. I'll try it out and see what happens! Thanks for your suggestions! I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working. I don't know if it's the "best" way, but I'm still learning. I created a Beacon struct to hold all beacon properties, created an array [Beacon] (my struct), then looped startScanning() over them. I removed the else statement in location manager (to stop updating .unknown), then matched my name label to the struct identifier. I'll probably look into table views for this in the future, but I just wanted to finish this tutorial without changing it too much for now! Thanks to you and David for all your help!